# What is the most efficient way to explicitly instantiate template class for many data types?

Tags: c++, function, templates, generic-programming, explicit-instantiation

Suppose I have a header file as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    template <typename U>
    int bar();

    template <typename U>
    int foobar();
};
```

I want to explicitly instantiate this class and all its methods to work with int, float and double types. Do I have to manually type out each instantiation or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes, if you want to explicitly instantiate you have to list all instantiations. Why do you need explicit instantiation? The better way is to use implicit instantiation.

Comment: An alternative would be to use SFINAE (`is_arithmetic_v`) to make it usable with those types only - but that wouldn't be explicit istantiation.